# Feeding information from one JS server into another with Ember

Tags: ember.js, server

We are currently using the Steam API for an Ember project, but have found out that the API doesn't allow cross-origin requests.  As a result, we created a server based of documentation found [here](https://codepen.io/johnchristopherjones/post/how-do-i-use-the-steam-api-in-my-web-app).

While we have created a server that is able to successfully call the API and get the info we requested, we have found that the server runs on port: 4000, and we need it to connect to port: 4200.

Is there a way for us to push the info from this server to the ember server?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the code we used for the server:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
    httpResponse.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.get('/hello-frank', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
httpResponse.send('Hello, Frank.');
});

app.post('/hello-frank', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
httpResponse.send("No, Frank. You're not allowed to post.");
});

app.get('/hello/:name', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
var name = httpRequest.params.name;
httpResponse.send('Hello, ' + name + '!');
});

var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/' +
'v2/?key=YOURSTEAMAPIKEYHERE&appid=8930';


request.get(url, function(error, steamHttpResponse, steamHttpBody) {
// Print to console to prove we downloaded the achievements.
console.log(steamHttpBody);
});

app.get('/steam/civ5achievements', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
// Calculate the Steam API URL we want to use
var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/' +
    'v2/?key=YOURSTEAMAPIKEYHERE&appid=8930';
request.get(url, function(error, steamHttpResponse, steamHttpBody) {
    // Once we get the body of the steamHttpResponse, send it to our client
    // as our own httpResponse
    httpResponse.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpResponse.send(steamHttpBody);
});
});


app.get('/steam/game/:appid/achievements', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
// Calculate the Steam API URL we want to use
var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/' +
    'v2/?key=YOURSTEAMAPIKEYHERE&appid=' +
    httpRequest.params.appid;
request.get(url, function(error, steamHttpResponse, steamHttpBody) {
    httpResponse.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpResponse.send(steamHttpBody);
});
});


app.use('/', express.static('public'));


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.text());


app.post('/frank-blog', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
console.log(httpRequest.body);

httpResponse.status(200).send('Posted today:\n\n' + httpRequest.body);

var port = 4000;
var server = app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

For developping purposes you could use the ember proxy function. Instead of starting the server like this:

```
ember s
```

you do it like this:

```
ember s --proxy=http://localhost:4000
```

As a result, all unknown HTTP requests get redirected to your server, assuming that your other server is on port 4000.